# What tool can I use to make 3D image designs?

Tags: image, 3d

I am trying to pictorially explain a system of application (ERP) with a 3D image (like the one attached). I can't seem to find any tool to simplistically help me achieve this purpose.

The simple one I found (TinkerCad) doesn't export the images in a satisfactory manner. I would appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Illustrator would do the trick for a lot of 3D stuff, like the isometric reference you've given but I'd strongly advise you to have a look at software like Blender (free) and Maxon's Cinema 4D for actual 3D modelling and rendering. That is, if you're planning on making numerous illustrations in this style. Modelling should be pretty easy, although lighting the scene perfectly would probably be a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool that will help you do this is Adobe Illustrator. Learn how to do Isometric illustrations in Adobe Illustrator.